# Rust window created with CreateWindowExW() does not receive winEventHook messages

Tags: windows, rust, windows-messages, windows-rs

So I setup windows hook for `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` event then in order to receive events from windows there must be message loop in the same thread, this requires setting up a window or using `GetMessage()`(this is not really an option for this case, because I listen for all windows, not just one). When I create message box with `MessageBoxW()` everything works fine, but this method is kinda ugly because box appears on the screen. I found out that I can create hidden window with `CreateWindowExW()`, after a while of experiments window was finally created but no events were passed to callback. I tried to create `HWND_MESSAGE` window which as described in Windows docs should be used for only messaging window, as well as random dummy window, but neither of them works.
Here's how it looks like:

```
...
// setting up event hook
let hook = unsafe {
    SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
        None,
        Some(win_event_hook_callback),
        0,
        0,
        0,
    )
};

if hook.0 == 0 {
    panic!("Could not setup WinEventHook");
}

info!("WinEventHook setup successful!");

// setting up class for window
let mut wc = WNDCLASSW::default();
let class_name = w!("randomclassname123");
wc.lpszClassName = class_name;
wc.lpfnWndProc = Some(window_proc);
wc.style = CS_GLOBALCLASS;
let wc_ptr: *const WNDCLASSW = &wc;

// registering class
let result = unsafe { RegisterClassW(wc_ptr) };

info!("RESULT: {:#?}", result);

// creating window
let hwnd: HWND = unsafe {
    CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
        wc.lpszClassName,
        w!("TITLE"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0,
        0,
        1000,
        1000,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        None,
    )
};
info!("HWND: {:#?}", &hwnd);

// sleeping to not to close thread immediately
std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(40000));
...
```

Comment: The OS makes the callback on the same thread that called SetWinEventHook().  Very nice, but can't happen when you make that thread catatonic on that sleep() call.  The window is quite dead as well.  Message loop required, call GetMessage/DispatchMessage().

Comment: Hmmm. Now I set things up in the main thread, without sleep(), but poiling function as future along with server future. I can get one message, and then after a few seconds app crashes with `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` error on, as I see with `RUST_BACKTRACE` `GetMessageW` call

Comment: Something wrong with win_event_hook_callback(), probably.  I can't see it.  Must be stdcall in 32-bit code.

Comment: this callback was working absolutely fine with `MessageBoxW()`, can it really be the problem?

Comment: Actually you are right. Because in `win_event_hook_callback()` I send my event to another place with unbounded channel, but before setting hook up I forgot to store unbounded sender in local thread storage. Now when I fixed that it works! Thank you!